# How to get the highest predicted value in multiclass classification problem using H2O AI?

Tags: h2o, multiclass-classification

When predicting values in a multiclass classification problem, I would like to get the probability of the predicted value.

I tried to solve this by using H2O's apply function:

```
predicted_df = modelo_assessor.predict(to_predict_h2o_frame)
predicted_df.apply((lambda x: x.max()), axis=1)
```

But it does not work:

> 'ValueError: unimpl bytecode instr: CALL_METHOD'

Maybe it doesn't work because h2o.max does not have axis parameter as h2o.mean does???
I couldn't find the documentation of which operations are supported on apply function.

I would like to solve the problem using h2o data manipulation similarly to this pandas code:

```
    predicted_df = modelo_assessor.predict(to_predict_h2o_frame).as_data_frame()
    predicted_df['PROB_PREDICTED']=predicted_df.iloc[:,1:].max(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening whenever using apply. Use the example from H2O documentation:

I was able to solve the problem by downgrading to Python 3.6.x

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2oframe

```py
python_lists = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
h2oframe = h2o.H2OFrame(python_obj=python_lists,
                        na_strings=['NA'])
colMean = h2oframe.apply(lambda x: x.mean(), axis=0)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-8da6b76c71bd> in <module>
      2 h2oframe = h2o.H2OFrame(python_obj=python_lists,
      3                         na_strings=['NA'])
----> 4 colMean = h2oframe.apply(lambda x: x.mean(), axis=0)

~/anaconda3/envs/h2o1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h2o/frame.py in apply(self, fun, axis)
   4910         assert_is_type(fun, FunctionType)
   4911         assert_satisfies(fun, fun.__name__ == "<lambda>")
-> 4912         res = lambda_to_expr(fun)
   4913         return H2OFrame._expr(expr=ExprNode("apply", self, 1 + (axis == 0), *res))
   4914 

~/anaconda3/envs/h2o1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h2o/astfun.py in lambda_to_expr(fun)
    133     code = fun.__code__
    134     lambda_dis = _disassemble_lambda(code)
--> 135     return _lambda_bytecode_to_ast(code, lambda_dis)
    136 
    137 def _lambda_bytecode_to_ast(co, ops):

~/anaconda3/envs/h2o1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h2o/astfun.py in _lambda_bytecode_to_ast(co, ops)
    147         body, s = _opcode_read_arg(s, ops, keys)
    148     else:
--> 149         raise ValueError("unimpl bytecode instr: " + instr)
    150     if s > 0:
    151         print("Dumping disassembled code: ")

ValueError: unimpl bytecode instr: CALL_METHOD
```